# Explanation of $E(\eta)=\int_0^{1}\min\left(\xi,\frac23\right)p(\xi)\,d\xi=\int_0^{2/3}\xi\,p(\xi)\,d\xi+\int_{2/3}^1\frac23\,p(\xi)\,d\xi.$

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

Also how would this differ if $\eta = min(\xi, \phi)$ and $\eta = min(\xi, \phi, \rho)$ where $ \eta, \phi, \rho$ are random variables.

Comment: In 1D you have only one variable. There is no $\phi$ or $\rho$.

Comment: The integral splits that way due to the definition of $\min(\xi,2/3)$. And for the other two cases, you can do something similar if joint densities of $(\xi,\phi)$ and $(\xi,\phi,\rho)$ are available. It follows from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) theorem.

Comment: By definition of the min function do you mean $\min(a,b) = \dfrac{a + b - \mid a - b \mid}{2}$?

Comment: $\min(a,b)=a$ if $a<b$ and $\min(a,b)=b$ if $a\ge b$.